# Unable to install JSS Server Package on Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure-search, jss

Installed SC9 update 1 using sitecore market place. I've been trying to setup JSS on Web Apps but not having any luck. When I try to install JSS Server package the installation process keeps spinning forever. I keep getting below error when trying to install JSS in azure web app. Works fine locally with SOLR. Any idea?

> ManagedPoolThread #4 04:06:40 FATAL Could not add field {9EDD2FCC-04AE-4230-84B4-C46C963F2284} : parameters for indexable sitecore://master/{5F8249B6-9290-4061-BD92-8DD72C7C6F7C}?lang=en&ver=1
>
> Exception: System.ApplicationException
>       Message: Conflict between type of incomming field 'Collection(Edm.String)' and field in schema 'Edm.String'
>
> Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
>       at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.CloudSearchIndexSchemaBuilder.AddFields(IndexedField[] fileds)
>       at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.CloudSearchIndexSchemaBuilder.AddField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue, CloudSearchFieldConfiguration configuration, CultureInfo culture)
>       at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchDocumentBuilder.AddField(String cloudName, Object fieldValue, CloudSearchFieldConfiguration cloudConfiguration, Boolean append, Boolean fieldIsEmpty)

Added this on `<exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">` but didn't solve forever installation spinner issue:

```
<Parameters>{9EDD2FCC-04AE-4230-84B4-C46C963F2284}</Parameters>
```

**Side effect (I think):**

I suspect because the installation hasn't been done properly I keep getting this error once JSS deployment has been done:

```
The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
  in img
Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
  in img
  at invariant (D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\myapp\server.bundle.js:873:15)
  at assertValidProps (D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\myapp\server.bundle.js:9457:63)
  at ReactDOMServerRenderer.renderDOM (D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\myapp\server.bundle.js:11177:5)
  at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\myapp\server.bundle.js:11031:21)
  at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\myapp\server.bundle.js:10967:19)
  at Object.renderToStaticMarkup
```

Kam and CharlesWood suggested to deploy with --env development but that didn't help either.
https://sitecorechat.slack.com/archives/C7JT0NRQW/p1527930809000016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to Azure Search.

If there are two or more fields with the same name but different types that need to be indexed, this causes issues with Azure Search. In this case, Sitecore field types are mapped to different Azure Search Edm types. As a result, when rebuilding an index, Sitecore XP tries to add values of different types to the same field, which is not supported by Azure and causes a conflict between the type of the incoming field and the field in the schema.

You have two solutions:

- Rename the field
- Exclude the filed from indexing

More information and also detailed solutions can be found here:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/137856

Comment: Yep read that KB, and added this below on field exclusion list. But no luck
<Parameters>{9EDD2FCC-04AE-4230-84B4-C46C963F2284}</Parameters>

Comment: Can you update your question with also config how you have excluded the field? Could be that this exclusion was misconfigured.

Comment: updated with more details

Comment: did you rebuild the index after excluding the field? Longer term we'll probably look at renaming it, but it should also be excluded. FWIW for 95% of cases you're probably just fine deleting the offending field entirely (OOTB apps are not using custom rendering contents resolvers)

Comment: I can now install the JSS package but react error still occurs. Will accept this answer and create new one for react issue

Answer (score 1):

If anyone face this issue, the solution is to exclude the field from indexing per below on :

```
<Parameters>{9EDD2FCC-04AE-4230-84B4-C46C963F2284}</Parameters>
```

Then rebuild the index and only re-install package.